# Why might this Tuple not work?

Tags: c#

In the documentation section of this site there is a piece on Tuples and Tuple support in C#7.0.  In that there is a very simple example of a tuple close to the start.

```
public (int sum, int count) GetTallies()
{
    return (1, 2);
}
```

I added this simple example to a class in my project and I have made sure that System.ValueTuple is properly referenced , yet intellisense is telling me that this is not fit to compile.

[image]

Has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before and could shed some light on why this might be happening.  This is in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Can you document the exact steps to take starting from the "New Project" dialog to get to your current position?

Comment: Did you install the appropriate package? - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/tuples.md

Comment: @AlexK. - the OP has already stated "I have made sure that System.ValueTuple is properly referenced" - does that not cover what you're asking?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it doesn't hurt to ask for verification.  Maybe the OP installed the wrong package?  Let's eliminate the obvious.

Comment: I was able to compile successfully with reference to System.ValueTuple (4.3.0) (I have copy pasted your code example above)